"Failed to Mount API filesystems". On copied drive with updated partition UUID's
So I directly cloned the partition layout of my main linux installation.
Which is Fedora 38, using commands as follows.
sgdisk --backup=table /dev/sda
sgdisk --load-backup=table /dev/sdb


I updated the UUID's and ALL references to them in the /etc directory and /boot and /boot/efi directories. Which are contained the grub configuration and mount tables after using gparted to update the UUID's of the various partitions.
I had noted at some point that in at least one version of the kernel I was running I had difficulty mounting multiple volumes with similar UUID's and when fstab was processed it would result in the wrong partition being loaded on boot for example.
When I select the startup device, from bios, and specify the sata to usb drive, it begins to boot.
However in both the case of the main HDD's installation and the External Sata to usb drive, boot freezes at "reached target basic system"..
When I disconnect the drive it works fine, all partitions are mountable alongside the main os and everything minus the aforementioned updated referencing files is the same.
I doublechecked that there was no file corruption or changes aside from those that were necessary.  The copies has been made using a command such as the following initially.
tar cf - . | (cd /mnt/dest && tar xvf -) 

To doublecheck everything was the same, I ran an rsync as well after the copy was complete and voila everything checked out.
To test my work I created a vmdk pointing to the drive using a raw disk and attempted to boot it via virtualbox.
It progresses further this time to:
"Failed to Mount API filesystems".
I must admit I'm a tad confused as to what the issue is.
Please note the following as well.
Using claude.ai I found some sites that allow you to search the whole linux and open source code base and found that this error comes directly from System-D.
As would seem it would a very familiar very long ago process and someone else by now must have discovered why this happens.
eg.
https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/systemd/systemd@296afa847704a61177b2ceea4dae4f2148cc27d0/-/blob/src/core/main.c
I am just wondering why it fails.  I have cloned drives directly using dd if/of and been able to run them via virtualbox with a usb 3 to sata connector many times as I have been doing now, I allocate plenty or RAM to the virtualbox instance and a couple cores, so I am questioning why this would happen.
Admittedly not really trying to do a custom build of system-d with additional debug points.
